# Default initial value for weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

When setting up a neural network, or any numeric optimization system using gradient descent, it's necessary to provide initial values for the weights (or whatever the system parameters are to be called).

One strategy is to initialize them to random values (set the random number seed to a known value, change for a different starting point). But this isn't always desirable (e.g. right now I'm comparing accuracy in single versus double precision, the TensorFlow random number generator outputs different values in each case). So I'm talking about a scenario where the initial values will be nonrandom.

Some initial value must be provided. In the absence of any information to specify a value, what should it be? The most obvious values are 0.0 and 1.0. Is there a reason to prefer one of those over the other?  Or is there some other value  that tends to be preferable for some reason?

Comment: Machine learning questions that don't involve any programming are better asked on Cross Validated. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/what-are-good-initial-weights-for-training-a-neural-network

Comment: Read any introductionary paper on the topic. This will effect in learning that the magnitude of those values is important (and depending on data and architecture) and much more important here: using a constant vector won't work in general (you have to break symmetry!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sascha observes, constant initial weights aren't a solution in general anyway because you have to break symmetry. Better solution for the particular context in which I came across the problem: a random number generator that gives the same sequence regardless of type.

```
dtype = np.float64

# Random number generator that returns the correct type
# and returns the same sequence regardless of type
def rnd(shape=(), **kwargs):
    if type(shape) == int or type(shape) == float:
        shape = shape,
    x = tf.random_normal(shape, **kwargs, dtype=np.float64)
    if dtype == np.float32:
        x = tf.to_float(x)
    return x.eval()
```